# What is an efficient way of breaking data into chunks in C?

Tags: c

I've been searching for hours and my google-fu has failed me so thought I'd just ask. Is there an easy and efficient way of breaking data into small chunks in C?

For example. If I collect a bunch of info from somewhere; database, file, user input, whatever. Then maybe use a serialization library or something to create a single large object in memory. I have the pointer to this object. Let's say somehow this object ends up being like... 500 kb or something. If your goal was to break this down into 128 byte sections. What would you do? I would like a kind of general answer, whether you wanted to send these chunks over network, store them in a bunch of little files, or pass them through a looped process or something. If there is not a simple process for all, but if there does exist some for specific use cases, that'd be cool to know too.

What has brought this question about: I've been learning network sockets and protocols. I often see discussion about packet fragmentation and the like. Lots of talk about chunking things and sending them in smaller parts. But I can never seem to find what they use to do this before they move on to how they send it over the network, which seems like the easy part... So I started wondering how large data would manually be broken up into chunks to send small bits over the socket at a time. And here we are.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I feel like your question is missing something. What's preventing you from taking the first 128 bytes, then the next 128 bytes, and so on?

Comment: The reason that you *"never seem to find what they use to do this"* is that there's actually nothing to do. Chunking is a concept, not a physical action. The 500 kb object can be viewed as an array of `char`. That array has a starting address and a length. To transmit the first "chunk", you pass the starting address, and a length of 128, to the "network_send" function. To transmit the second "chunk", you pass the starting address + 128, and a length of 128, to the "network_send" function. The length is 128 for every chunk except the last, which might be shorter.

Comment: `What would you do?` I probably wouldn't have combined everything into a single blob if I didn't want a single blob.

Comment: Not sure why my question is getting downvoted... but thanks for the comments... I'll elaborate on each one at a time. Starting with:

@Siguza The question you ask is essentially the question I'm asking. How would you 'take the first 128 bytes, then the next, and so on? Is there specific functions?

Comment: @user3386109 I see what you are saying. And that is a more specific use case. If that is just 'how it is done' then that's cool. I just wasn't certain if there are other ways.

Comment: @Brendan That would probably be the ideal approach. But that was just an example, what if the situation requires you to handle something that has already been combined?

Comment: @Pewsplosions A search term you may be interested in is [zero copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy).

Comment: @user3386109 Yes. Very interested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easy and efficient way of breaking data into small chunks in C?

### Data is *practically* a consecutive sequence of bytes.

**You could use [memmove](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) to copy or move it** and slice it in smaller chunks (e.g. of 1024 bytes each).  For non-overlapping data, consider [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy). In practice, a [byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) is often a `char` (perhaps an `unsigned char` or a `signed char`) but see also the standard [`uint8_t` type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) and related types. In practice, you can cast `void*` from or to `char*` on [Von Neumann architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture) (like x86 or [RISC-V](https://riscv.org/)).

Beware of [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

In practice I would recommend organizing data at a higher level.

If your [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) is Linux or Windows or MacOSX or Android, you could consider using a [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) library such as [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) (or indexed files à la [Tokyo Cabinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Cabinet_and_Kyoto_Cabinet)). It is [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) software, and doing such slicing at the disk level.

If you have no operating system and your C code is freestanding (**read the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)** for the terminology) things are becoming different. For example, a typical computer mouse contains a [micro-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) whose code is mostly in C. Look into [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) for inspiration (and also [RaspBerryPi](http://raspberrypi.org/)). You'll have to then handle data at the bit level.

> But I can never seem to find what they use to do this before they move on to how they send it over the network, which seems like the easy part...

#### You'll find lots of open source network code.

The Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/) has some. [FreeRTOS](https://freertos.org/) has some. [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) has some. [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) has some. [Contiki](http://www.contiki-os.org/) has some. [OSdev](https://osdev.org/) links to more resources (notably on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](http://gitlab.com/)). **You could download such source code and study it.**

You'll find many [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) ([libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion), [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), etc...) or [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) ([postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), [vmime](https://vmime.org/), etc...) related networking open source programs on Linux etc... And other network programs ([PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/), etc...).  **Study their source code**

Comment: This is actually great stuff. Thank you for the answer. Pretty much exactly what I was hoping for. I kind of know some of it but I'm still pretty easily tripped up with pointers and memory management in general having come from higher level languages mostly. So this really helps fill in those gaps for me. (Not sure why people on this site are so quick to downvote and belittle people's questions... So thank you for giving it consideration and a well laid out answer.)